# makeSceneTransitionAnimation RecyclerView

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-animation

i'm trying to use a Transition animation from a RecyclerView to an activity

Ì'm following this

https://www.uplabs.com/posts/shared-element-transition-kotlin

But when i need to do this

```
val detailIntent = Intent(mActivity, LargeImageDetailActivity::class.java)
val imageViewPair = Pair.create<View, String>(imageView, "YourTransitionName")
val textViewPair = Pair.create<View, String>(textView, "YourTransitionName")
val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(mActivity, imageViewPair, textViewPair)

detailIntent.putExtra(LargeImageDetailActivity.DATA, data) // pass your bundle data
startActivity(detailIntent, options.toBundle())
```

I need to replace mActivity for my activity. But i cannot find how to do it from a RecyclerView Adapter

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone faces the same problem, i found a solution

```
fun getActivity(context: Context?): Activity {
        return if (context is Activity) {
            context
        } else {
            getActivity((context as ContextWrapper).baseContext)
        }
    }
```

and then

```
var actividad : Activity = getActivity(context)
val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(actividad,p1,p2,p3)
            context.startActivity(intent,options.toBundle())
```